# Data Explorer: Integer parameters can't be negative values

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

With the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), when using "strongly-typed" integer parameters in the form of `##VariableName:int##`, you can't enter negative values. When attempting to do so, you get an error message:

> Expected value of VariableName to be a int!

You can try this for yourself; I noticed this while composing a [simple "worst answers" query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/60849/worst-answers) with a user-supplied cutoff score. Attempting to enter negative scores causes this error, while values of 0 and above work. (*Don't try this at <s>home</s> Stack Overflow, kids!*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it seems that the numeric typed (both `int` and `float`) parameters never accepted negative values. I've gone ahead and [updated the value checks](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=0c96cf56f649859ab2d817b5045c667d3c69af09) to allow this, so now your example works in my local environment.

I imagine that this was just an overlooked use case, so hopefully it'll be pulled and Data Explorer updated soon, unless waffles had a reason for this being the way it was.